# Understanding how DNS will point to new site

Tags: wordpress, dns

Please can someone help me to clarify what issues i might have when the hosting company changes the DNS settings to point away for the current old site (basic html) and to the new WordPress version of the web site?

Both sites are with the same hosting company (I cannot change hosts or hosting names now, my client and the hosting company are long term business partners). I think the server that the current live website is unable to host WordPress. So they set up another server for WordPress and called it something completely different.

Old website address *http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk*
Current Location of new WordPress site on hosting server: *http://test.blahsystems.co.uk*

I think this bit is important!!
The new website is on a Windows Server and uses pretty perma links and also the .html pages plugin. There are also some redirects going to 7 pages on the old site. Everything is currently working ok.

Nest week the hosting company are going to change the DNS settings to point to the new website *http://test.blahsystems.co.uk* which will hopefully become the new website with the new address of *http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk*

The hosting company have also said that I should not have used Permalinks at the moment because once the DNS is pointed to the new site the links will have become permanent (well I had already set up permalinks before they told me). I have not used the full address when making any links within the site.

Will the 'Find & Replace' plug-in on the database still work ok to make any required changes? I am confused as to how the DNS change actually works, will this affect what the links are called in the database or can I still change them from:
*http://test.blahsystems.co.uk*
to
*http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk*

I presume I will need to change the Word Press address and site address in the settings panel to http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk, once the DNS propagation has finished.

Very long winded I know but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wordpress is utterly horrible for migrating. It's simple to dump the DB and reimport elsewhere, but basically you'll find that every internal "self" link in the entire system will be broken, because WP stores the full absolute `http://originalsite.com/path/to/post` url INSIDE the blog posts records.

Comment: Ok, but does that mean I can still use the "find & replace" plug-in and change any hard coded links to the new site address? I am not really sure how the DNS change will affect this. I have done this with other sites ok, but have never done it with a site that is being redirected through DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I will do the best I can to answer these 8-)

> Please can someone help me to clarify what issues i might have when
>   the hosting company changes the DNS settings to point away for the
>   current old site (basic html) and to the new WordPress version of the
>   web site?

When you change your DNS - it's like moving into a new house.
The whole building can change - so it sounds like you're leaving a Windows environment for a Linux environment. Which is cool.

What happened on the old site - should not really impact the new site OTHER than the fact that search engines will still try to remember the old sites structure. It will take time for the search engine to realize that things have changed and that pages are new or missing.

301 Redirection can help with this.

> Both sites are with the same hosting company (I cannot change hosts or
>   hosting names now, my client and the hosting company are long term
>   business partners). I think the server that the current live website
>   is unable to host WordPress. So they set up another server for
>   WordPress and called it something completely different.
>
> Old website address http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk Current
>   Location of new WordPress site on hosting server:
>   http://test.blahsystems.co.uk
>
> I think this bit is important!! The new website is on a Windows Server
>   and uses pretty perma links and also the .html pages plugin. There are
>   also some redirects going to 7 pages on the old site. Everything is
>   currently working ok.

WordPress can use permalinks. If you have moved pages around - like mysite.com/about-us and it's not called mysite.com/about - you will need to create a 301 Redirect to let search engines know.

> Nest week the hosting company are going to change the DNS settings to
>   point to the new website http://test.blahsystems.co.uk which will
>   hopefully become the new website with the new address of
>   http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk
>
> The hosting company have also said that I should not have used
>   Permalinks at the moment because once the DNS is pointed to the new
>   site the links will have become permanent (well I had already set up
>   permalinks before they told me). I have not used the full address when
>   making any links within the site.

I don't think using permalinks will cause a problem. They aren't "permanent". Nothing is - it's all in a transient state.

> Will the 'Find & Replace' plug-in on the database still work ok to
>   make any required changes? I am confused as to how the DNS change
>   actually works, will this affect what the links are called in the
>   database or can I still change them from:
>   http://test.blahsystems.co.uk to http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk

Sounds like this plugin is outside of the WordPress install? If so - it should still work.
If it's a plugin your hosting provider is giving you, then there should be no problems.

> I presume I will need to change the Word Press address and site
>   address in the settings panel to http://www.therealwebsitename.co.uk,
>   once the DNS propagation has finished.

Yes, make sure to update your General Settings prior to the site going live so you don't have any down time.